# "Brought by" usage

Tags: meaning

Our tiny company has a blog, in which under the blog name, the company logo appears as:

> *[Blog Name]* **brought by** *[Company Name]*

Are we using **brought by** properly to convey that this publication is sponsored by the company?

Thank you!

Comment: The bitransitive can support *to you* as well: "(Blog Name) brought **to you** by (Company)."

Comment: "Brought by" or "brought to you by" (as @Kris suggests) seem to me to indicate that the company sponsors or pays for the blog (as the sole advertiser, for example), not necessarily that the company is fully responsible for writing the blog.